# Can I create multiple virtual devices from multiple GPUs in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, multi-gpu

I'm using [Local device configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/set_logical_device_configuration) in Tensorflow 2.3.0 currently, to simulate multiple GPU training, and it is working. If I buy another GPU, will I be able to use the same functionality to each GPU?

Right now I have 4 virtual GPUs and one physical GPU. I want to buy another GPU and want to have 2x4 virtual GPUs. I haven't found any information about it, and because I don't have another GPU right now, I can't test it. Is it supported? I'm afraid, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have additional GPU, since there is no restriction in the number of GPU's you can make use of all the GPU devices you have.
As you can see in the document also which says,

> A visible tf.config.PhysicalDevice will by default have a single
> tf.config.LogicalDevice associated with it once the runtime is
> initialized. Specifying a list of tf.config.LogicalDeviceConfiguration
> objects allows multiple devices to be created on the same
> tf.config.PhysicalDevice

You can follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) documentation for more details on usage of multiple GPU's.